# Why is Chrome generating unnecessary huge margins?

Tags: html, css

web site in progress http://www.asstatauka.us.lt

In firefox it looks fine, but Chrome and other webkit internet browsers are generating margins at the bottom and on the right side. Can anybody inspect my code and advice me on what I could change to avoid this problem. I would appreciate. Many thanks!

Comment: Nervous to follow the link at work...

Comment: what do you mean by SFW?

Comment: @DonnyRevalio Safe for work =)

Answer (score 0):

```
div#top-header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#cart-top {
    right: 0;
}
```

Add this to CSS file accordingly.

Comment: this didnt help. Actually it removed the bottom of my cart, but nothing to do with the margin on the right.

Comment: I didn't read about the right margin, sorry about that. Updated. FYI, when you use `right/left/top/bottom` it calculates the position according to the whole page, unlike `margin-left/right/top/bottom`